# How many ways to arrange numbers $1,\dots,n$ such that

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many ways are there to arrange the numbers $1, 2, \ldots, n$ in a line such that each number to the left of the number in place $k$ is smaller than the number in place $k$ ?

I have started by selecting for a certain k the permutations for $1,\dots,k-1$ and multiplied it by the number of permutations for $k,\dots,n$.

However, that gives me a lot of repetition.

For example, for $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ I counted the combination $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ five times, and many more permutations.

How can I get rid of them? Is there a different way?

Comment: Is there any arrangement possible other than $1,2,\dots ,n$?

Comment: for $A={1,2,3,4}, k=3$ the possible permutations are $(1,2,3,4),(2,1,3,4),(1,2,4,3),(2,1,4,3)$ because the number in place k is larger than numbers 1,2.

Comment: Oh, I thought the OP was asking sequences where it is valid $\forall k \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$

Comment: Were you asking how many permutations have at least one $k$ with this arrangement, or do you have specific $n$ and $k$?

Comment: If $n$ is in the first position, it is true for no $k$.  Otherwise, it is true for $k$=position of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your permutation be $\pi$, and let $\pi_i$ denote the value in the $i$-th position of $\pi$.

Note that there are $\pi_k - 1$ values which are less than the value of $\pi_k$. We want to choose $k-1$ of these since we have to "fill in" the $k-1$ spots before it in the permutation. There are $(k-1)!$ permutations on this set.

So we have 
$$
\binom{\pi_k-1}{k-1}\cdot(k-1)!
$$
permutations on the elements before the $k$-th position.

Now consider the elements that occur after the $k$-th position.
We have already chosen and placed $k$ elements (the $k-1$ before $k$ and $k$ itself.) So we have to perform any permutation on the $n-k$ elements left so there are $(n-k)!$ of these.

Overall we therefore have that the number of permutations that you're looking for on $n$ elements with the $k$-th forming the limit in the way specified
$$
\#\text{perms}(k,n) = \underbrace{\binom{\pi_k-1}{k-1}\cdot(k-1)!}_{\text{elements before }k}\underbrace{\cdot(n-k)!}_{\text{elements after }k}
$$

Comment: I think the full solution would be a summation over $\pi_k$ from $k$ to $n$, although this depends on a particular interpretation of the question (which is not at all clear).

Comment: but why $\binom{\pi _{k}-1}{k-1}$? the order does matter.

Comment: That's why there's the $(k-1)!$ factor, you need to chose which elements you are using, then permute amongst them. You can't just permute the $k-1$, as this would only consider if you only had $k-1$ elements to choose from rather than every element less than $\pi_k$

Answer (score 5):

The number is $n!/k$.  The chance that the highest of $k$ random numbers is the $k$th one is one in $k$.
For example, with $n=4$ and $k=3$, the answer is 8, because they are 
$$\{1,2,3,4\},\{2,1,3,4\},\{1,2,4,3\},\{2,1,4,3\},\\
\{3,1,4,2\},\{3,2,4,1\},\{1,3,4,2\},\{2,3,4,1\}$$

Comment: Nice and concise! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Michael's first answer, you can obtain the result without referring to chances combinatorically:

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to pick a set of numbers for the first $k$ entries. Now the $k$th entry has to be maximal among the first $k$, so you can only permute the $k-1$ remaining entries. For the entries right from the $k$th, you can freely permute, so the number of possible arrangements is
$$
\binom{n}{k} (k-1)!(n-k)! = \frac{n!}{k}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comment, perhaps he is looking for a cut where all numbers to the left are smaller than all numbers to the right.  Then, in OP, he talks about repetition, so he might be looking for all permutations with at least one cut.
Let $F(n)$ be the number of arrangements with at least one cut; so $G(n)=n!-F(n)$ is the number with no cuts.  For example, $F(1)=0,F(2)=1,F(3)=3$.
Let the first cut be between the first $k$ numbers and the rest.  The remaining $n-k$ numbers can have any arrangement.  So
$$F(n)=G(1)(n-1)!+G(2)(n-2)!+...+G(n-1)1!\\=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k!(n-k)!-F(k)(n-k)!$$
$G(n)$ starts $1,1,3,13,71,461,...$, which is sequence A003319 in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.